# How to make images in Bootstrap 4 slider responsive?

Tags: html, css

I am creating website page using bootstrap 4  slider, but images are not responsive and it looks good only in 1980x1080.
How to make images responsive?

My code looks like that:

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="7000">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item active img-fluid" style="background-image: url(img/slide11.jpg);">
            <div class="carousel-caption text-center">
                <h1><img class="hydrive_logo" src="img/Hydrive_logo.png" alt="Hydrive - logo"/></h1>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg" href="#Bolid">Get Started</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url(img/HydriveTeam.jpg);"></div>
        <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url(img/HydriveShell.jpg);"></div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you set the images to be as backgrounds for `.carousel-item` AND you don't have any other content on those items you should set couple more properties in order to see those images. Example:

```css
.carousel-item {
  height: 400px; /* set some height*/
  /* optionals */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;  
  background-position: cneter;
  background-size: 100% 100%; 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="7000">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item active img-fluid" style="background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/1000x1000?text=First+Slide);">
            <div class="carousel-caption text-center">
                <img class="hydrive_logo" src="img/Hydrive_logo.png" alt="Hydrive - logo"/>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg" href="#Bolid">Get Started</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/1000x1000?text=Second+Slide);"></div>
        <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/1000x1000?text=Third+Slide);"></div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

**As a side note: you can't use image as header, so don't place `img` inside `h1`.**